# Websocket connection to Hot Chocolate GraphQL server fails in local environment

Tags: asp.net, websocket, graphql, visual-studio-mac, hotchocolate

Hello Hot Chocolate Community,

I'm having trouble setting up websockets for my Hot Chocolate GraphQL server in my local environment. I have followed the documentation and added `app.UseWebSockets()` to my ASP.NET Core application, which is running on my local machine. However, when I try to connect to the websocket at `ws://localhost:7217/graphql/` using `wscat`, I get the error "socket hang up". Similarly, when I try to connect from my React app using Apollo Client, I get the error "**websocket connection to `'ws://localhost:7217/graphql/ws`' failed**".

I would appreciate any help in figuring out what is causing the issue. Here are some additional details:

- I'm using Hot Chocolate version 13
- I'm running the server on macOS and testing with wscat on the command line
- I am starting the server via visual studio for mac
- I have not made any other changes to my application's configuration
- I'm able to make regular
  HTTP requests to the server and receive valid responses

Thank you for
your assistance.

Comment: Visual studio is in fact not responsible for websocket settings

Comment: Hotchocolate is also listining to the same url and port as for http requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of investigation and texting with the hotchocolate stuff, which indeed is very open to help. (Checkout there Slack channel).

I tried again via Apollo Client and checked how the connection got established via Banana Cake Pop: They use `wss` instead of `ws`, which is great for me.

So I could establish the connection with apollo client by switching the uri to wss